# After statistically successful training, the results are not reflecting such through a live camera. How do I fix this problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have been using TensorFlow for milk carton detection on Linux. The language being used is python. The model being used is faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets. I am new with machine learning. This is my first time learning how to do object detection, please help!

Our dataset: We have taken photos of each milk carton individually (around 130 photos per milk carton) in the same environment (fridge shelf). We have taken mixed photos of multiple milk cartons(around 400 photos).

Here is the evidence that the training was supposedly successful:[Evidence 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk5g0.jpg)
[Evidence 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZZfQ.jpg) [Evidence 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkdl0.jpg)

Here is how we labeled the cartons: [Using OpenLabeler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCWXd.jpg)

Here is the live camera feed which is not accurate(the problem): [Evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNoP7.jpg)

The code:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Inception v2, configured for Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 6
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          decay_steps: 5000
          decay_factor: 0.9
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/konbini/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 150000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}


train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 288
  # Number of images in testing folder
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

When we did the augmentation for any kind of color change the results got worse. When we did the augmentation for any kind of rotation the results were the same. [Evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoEhu.jpg)

I have two questions: is there any problem with our data set? is there any problem with our labeling method?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of your model got overfitted to training dataset and therefore not generalized enough to handle test dataset. I can see that you haven't used augmentation techniques except `random_horizontal_flip` in your config file which could have helped to generalize your model better. You can add augmentation techniques under `train_config` section like follows:

```
train_config: {
  ...
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_rotation90 {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_distort_color {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }
  .....
}
```

All available augmentation techniques can be found in [preprocessor.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto):

Comment: When we did the augmentation for any kind of color change the results got worse. When we did the augmentation for any kind of rotation the results were the same. 

Our dataset: We have taken photos of each milk carton individually (around 130 photos per milk carton) in the same environment (fridge shelf). We have taken mixed photos of multiple milk cartons(around 400 photos). 

I have two questions: is there any problem with our data set? is there any problem with our labeling method?

Comment: I posted the augmentation evidence above just now, so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Which script did you use for the training, anyway? Was it "model_main.py" or "train.py"?

I'm asking because I'm not sure whether the "Evidence" plots you posted are showing the loss on the training, or on the evaluation set. You seem to be using the PASCAL VOC metrics, and I'm not familiar with them, in general I use the COCO metrics.
In case you aren't sure about it (sorry, I'm just asking because you said you're new to this) you can check it simply by moving your mouse over the plots, it will show a box like this:

[image]

Here, you can clearly see that the curves are referring to the evaluation set (the eval_0 in the legend).

If it's not like this, it means that you're visualizing the loss on the training set. In  this case, the fact that the loss decreases is expected, but it doesn't mean that the model will be able to generalize on new data. To be sure of that, the validation loss is a better indicator.